# Genymotion error :Unable to create the virtual device server returned HTTP status code 0

Tags: emulation, genymotion

While trying to create a new virtual device in Genymotion 
the following error is shown:

```
Unable to create the virtual device 
Server returned HTTP status code 0
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings in genymotion
in general tab give your user name and password
and in virtual box tab assign where genymotion is insatlled
in adb tab assign the sdk path

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Network

check Use HTTP Proxy

set HTTP Proxy 1.234.45.50
 set Port 3128

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that system **date and time** is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to BIOS and enable virtualization under the advanced settings.